# Remove text/lines between search patterns

Tags: awk, sed

Coding to delete an entire line is easy, but I am trying to figure out how to delete between reg expressions. Instead of the technical report I am working with, I wrote up a more interesting example:

Current text:

```
 cactus in the desert blooms @year round
 and almost all cactus plants have very sharp needles
 ------ that may hurt you if you get too close-----
 so stay away from the needles all @year and admire the 
     many colors in the buds @and flowers

 more data more data more data

 cactus in the desert blooms @year round
 and almost all cactus plants have very sharp needles
 so stay away from the needles all @year and admire the 
 data more data more data @year
 data more data more data more data @year
     many colors in the buds @and flowers
more data
 cactus in the desert blooms @year round
 and almost all cactus plants have very sharp needles
    so stay away from the needles all @year and admire the 
     many colors in the buds @and flowers

more data more data
more data more data
more data more data
```

In this case I am using `@year` as the initial reg expression and `@and` as the second. I want to delete delete partial and full lines in between the reg expressions. Prefer to use SED.

Note: any subsequent instance of `@year` needs to be ignored until `@and` is found. If multiple instances of `@and` are found, no action should be performed because there was no preceding instance of `@year`.

Result wanted for all examples shown:

```
 cactus in the desert blooms and flowers

 more data more data more data

 cactus in the desert blooms and flowers
 more data more data more data

 cactus in the desert blooms and flowers
 more data
 cactus in the desert blooms and flowers

 more data more data
 more data more data
 more data more data
```

Comment: Could you please do let us know if you could have multiple occurrences of `@and` ? If yes then do you want to match till the last occurrence of it or any specific instance of it? OR do you have only these exact lines in your actual Input_file as per shown samples itself? Kindly confirm on these once.

Comment: You're missing all of the usual use cases for a problem like this from your example and textual requirements, e.g. how to handle 2 `@year`s before a `@and`, 2 `@and`s after one `@year`, an `@and` with no preceding `@year`, a `@year` with no subsequent `@and`, etc. so you're getting solutions for the one sunny-day case you show - where there is always a single `@year` and `@and` pair in your input. If that's not what you need then [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide more realistic sample input/output.

Comment: You're also getting solutions that assume `@` cant appear anywhere else in your input since it doesn't in the example you posted. If that's a bad assumption then, again, [edit] your example to include more `@`s (and cases where `@year` or `@and` can appear as a substring, like `joe@andoverplumbers.com`, etc.)

Comment: The file contains naturally occurring `@` signs, but I swap out those for a space using SED. I will swap in `@year` and `@and`. Regexp `@and` is certain to be consistent. However because of the swap that I have to make to insert `@year`, it is likely to appear multiple times on different lines before `@and` appears in the file. So the search needs to switch on when `@year` is first found, and then switched off after `@and` is found. I will add this to my example.

Comment: If the example in your question doesn't cover all of your use cases then edit your question to show more truly realistic example(s). Also, don't add textual requirements in comments - [edit] your question to contain all relevant information.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that I was not thorough in my example. I have updated it and I hope it is sufficient intel to get the corrections to the commands that are needed.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, completely based on your shown samples in GNU `awk`.
In case you are NOT having any empty lines in your Input_file try.

```
awk -v RS= '{sub(/@year.*@and/,"and")} 1' Input_file
```

With shown samples output will be:

```
 cactus in the desert blooms and flowers
```

Comment: `sub` is greedy and might absorb multiple passages in one go.

Comment: @kvantour, agreed but that's why I had written "its written as per shown samples", if OP comes with some samples/examples where its needed something else on this one will edit the answer then.

Comment: @kvantour, I have left a comment for OP on this one, lets see what OP says.

Comment: Does the `"and"` you show refer the `@and`? Or is it supposed to a literal regardless of the two regexps `@year` and `@and`. If the regexps were `@year` and `@limit`, would `"and"` still be in there or would it become `"limit"`?

Comment: @985ranch, basically its written as per your shown samples and it considers whole para as a single line and simply substitute from `@year` to `@and` with and, which produces your sample output.

Answer (score 2):

With your file named `cactus`, you could do:

```
$ sed ':a; N; s/\n/ /; ta' cactus | sed 's/[@][^@][^@]*[@]//'
 cactus in the desert blooms and flowers
```

The leading `' '` before `"cactus"` remains that you can remove if you like.

Using Extended Regex on the second expression it reduces to:

```
sed ':a; N; s/\n/ /; ta' cactus | sed -E 's/@[^@]+@//'
```

Comment: But won't this alter lines of the file which are before and after the delimiters?

Comment: You can tighten or narrow the search as needed. Simply changing the removal to, e.g. `'s/@year[^@]+@and/and/'` will limit the removal between `@year` and `@and` with `and` substituted in it's place. With BRE that is `sed 's/@year[^@][^@]*@and/and/'`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed for -z:

```
$ sed -z 's/@year.*@and/and/' file
 cactus in the desert blooms and flowers
```

Comment: Dont' forget to mention `.*` is greedy so if there are two or more sets of `@year` thru `@and` in the file, this solution will remove everything between the first `@year` and the last `@and`.

Comment: I didn't forget, I commented under the question about there being MANY potential use cases that are missing from the question so the OP is just getting solutions that work for the one sunny-day case shown. Your answer, for example, assumes the OP wants to delete the text between `@year` and **the first** `@and` that follows it. Maybe they want to delete from the first `@year` to the last `@and` or something else. We just don't know what the OP wants to do for anything except that one sunny-day case in the question.

Comment: This came very close. It passed by the cases when only `@and` was found, which was good. When it found both regexps and took action, it did delete lines and partial lines in between, however then a few more lines down there was an empty line, and all lines below the empty line were also deleted.

Comment: When I left `"and"` as a literal, it did not delete the remainder of the file, so changing it to be similar to the regexp was my not understanding it, however the partial lines were not deleted. When `@year` occurred followed by another `@year` on a following line, then `@and` occurred, it did not delete everything from the first instance of `@year` through `@and`.

Comment: All of the solutions posted are designed to work with the example you showed, that's all. You shouldn't expect any of them to work with anything that you didn't show. Sounds like you do have all the common use cases to consider (see my comments under your question) so describe how you want them handled and include them in examples in your question if you want a solution that handles every case you want handled.

Comment: I updated my example yesterday. Please take look when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl,

```
$ cat ranch.txt
 cactus in the desert blooms @year round
 and almost all cactus plants have very sharp needles
 ------ that may hurt you if you get too close-----
 so stay away from the needles and admire the
     many colors in the buds @and flowers
$ perl -0777 -pe ' s/(?:\@year)(.+)(?:\@and)/and/gms ' ranch.txt
 cactus in the desert blooms and flowers
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is at most one `@` in each line I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be:

```
 cactus in the desert blooms @year round
 and almost all cactus plants have very sharp needles
 ------ that may hurt you if you get too close-----
 so stay away from the needles and admire the 
     many colors in the buds @and flowers
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="@";ORS="";doprint=1}
(NF<=1){if(doprint)print}
(NF>1){doprint=!doprint;print doprint?$2:$1}' file.txt
```

output

```
 cactus in the desert blooms and flowers
```

Explanation: I set field seperator to `@` and output record seperator to nothing (empty string) and set `doprint` to true. Then for every line with no more than 1 field (i.e. without @) I just `print` it if doprint holds true and for every line with more than 1 field (i.e. holding @) I negate `doprint`, then if it was set to true I print what was beyond `@` else what was before `@`.

Answer (score 0):

And also with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="@";ORS=""} /@year/ {print $1} /@and/{print $2"\n"}' file
cactus in the desert blooms and flowers
```

Comment: This command just seems to replace every line in the file with the word 'and'.

Comment: Excuse me. The input data have changed! This code tested with `gnu-awk` is only for the previous input data.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/@year/{:b;/@and/!{N;bb};s/\n//g;s/@year/\n/;s/@and/\nand/;s/\n.*\n//;ba}' file
```

Gather up lines in the pattern space containing both `@year` and `@and`.

Remove all newlines in the collection.

Replace `@year` by `\n` and `@and` by `\nand`.

Remove everything between the introduced newlines.

Repeat.

N.B. This will cater for two or more sets of start and end delimiters on the same line.